# Last milliseconds of a day in ISO format in Java

Tags: java, jodatime

I have string representations of dates that I need to convert to Date objects. I need the start of the day and the end of the day in datetime down to the millisecond. Here is what I have so far:

date format is:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'
```

start of day:

```
2013-05-19T00:00:00+00:00
```

end of day:

```
2013-05-19T23:59:59+59:59
```

The 'start of day' parses ok but the 'end of day' throws

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2013-05-19T23:59:59+59:59" is malformed at "59:59"
```

Comment: End of day: `2013-05-19T23:59:59+00:00` The `+00:00` is about time zone, not about millisecond.

Comment: @johnchen902: No, that's missing out the milliseconds.

Comment: By the way, trying to determine the last moment of the day is an awkward and unwise way to handle date-time values. Instead, learn about *Half-Open* comparisons where the beginning of a span of time is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bit after the `+` isn't milliseconds. The `+` introduces a timezone offset. `+00:00` is GMT (Greenwich Mean Time). `+01:00` is an hour later (CET; Central European Time).

For the very last millisecond of the day, you want:

```
2013-05-19T23:59:59.999
Milliseconds -------^^^
```

Note that that's a `.` before the `999`, because what we're really writing there is `59.999` seconds.

If you want to, you can add a timezone indicator on that, e.g.:

```
2013-05-19T23:59:59.999+00:00
```

[More about ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).